# Change Table format from within MySQL 8?

Tags: mysql-8.0, format

Is there a mysql command to change the output format of a table?
Specifically, I'd like to get rid of the formatting '-'s and '+'s:

```
+------+------------+
| ID   | Name       |
+------+------------+
| 1523 | Wien       |
| 1524 | Graz       |
+------+------------+
```

### I tried:

Appending

```
--result-format=tabbed
```

to my docker exec command:

```
docker exec -it [DB-container-name] mysql -uroot -p --result-format=tabbed
```

as I gathered from [this MySQL page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-output-table-format.html), but this gives me "unknown variable".

Comment: What you see is the User Interface (UI) interpretation of the data.  If the UI was a web page, the results will have the appropriate HTML tags. ( `<table>`, `<tr>`,`<td>`, etc.)  Configure the UI to display how you want it or use a different UI.  Better yet, describe your Business Requirement and someone should be able to point you to the appropriate method.

Comment: What data type is this in this case? I'm using xfce Terminal.